# Hide or remove button from external application

Tags: c#, wpf, user32

I am runnig an external application from my WPF Project and I am putting external app inside my WPF form with using "user32.dll"

External app has an exit button. I would like to remove or hide that button. Can I do that "using user32.dll" or different approach?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to build this *external* app?

Comment: @OmegaMan Yes that is external exe file. I would like to access that's button.

Comment: Is this exit button a part of the standard frame or a random button on its screen?

Comment: @OmegaMan that is random button. It has got an exit button. I would like to remove or hide that.

Comment: This is frowned upon.  This is an action that is viewed as something that virii or malicious software does and can often be flagged by anti-malware systems.  Also, depending on how a system is configured or the version of Windows, those times of things can be access violations.  It's much better to write cooperative applications; as Omegaman points out, named pipes is one way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The below code finds the button and hides it. It works gracefully on my system. The code searches for the window title and then find the control. You have to provide the window title and button text. You can update the code as per your need.

Note: Below code will hide all the controls with the matching text specified in the constant TEXT_BUTTON.

```
const string TEXT_TITLE = "My Specific Window";
const string TEXT_BUTTON = "&HideMeButton";

public delegate bool EnumWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr parameter);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);
const int SW_HIDE = 0;

[DllImport("user32")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumWindowProc callback, IntPtr i);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowText", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr GetWindowCaption(IntPtr hwnd, StringBuilder lpString, int maxCount);  

public void HideSpecificButton()
{            
    //Contains the handle, can be zero if title not found
    var handleWindow = WinGetHandle(TEXT_TITLE);
    if (GetWindowCaption(handleWindow).Trim() != TEXT_TITLE)
        MessageBox.Show("Window is hidden or not running.");
    else
        GetChildWindows(handleWindow);            
}

public IntPtr WinGetHandle(string title)
{
    IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
    foreach (Process pList in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (pList.MainWindowTitle.Contains(title))
        {
            hWnd = pList.MainWindowHandle;
        }
    }
    return hWnd; 
}

private string GetWindowCaption(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
    GetWindowCaption(hwnd, sb, 256);
    return sb.ToString();
}

public void GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)
{
    List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
    GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
    try
    {
        EnumWindowProc childProc = new EnumWindowProc(EnumControls);
        EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
    }
    finally
    {
        if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
            listHandle.Free();
    }
}

private bool EnumControls(IntPtr handle, IntPtr pointer)
{
    var controlTitle = GetWindowCaption(handle).Trim();
    if (string.Equals(controlTitle, TEXT_BUTTON, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        //hide the control
        ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "using user32.dll"

No you can't use user32.dll for each app is in their own sandbox so to speak and should be impervious to outside unwanted actions.

> (Q: Do you have access to build this external app? A: Y ) ...or different approach?

Since you have access to the code of both apps, have them implement an interprocess named pipe. In the receiving app have it monitor the pipe for a message to turn off the button(s) or change its windows frame style.

See

[How to: Use Named Pipes for Network Interprocess Communication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx)